# Через некоторое время работы программы ncurses не правильно отображает информацию

Tags: c, ncurses

Есть следующий код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct Player
{
    unsigned int allScores;
    unsigned int firstDiceScores;
    unsigned int secondDiceScores;
};

int  interceptKeystroke();
int  changePlayerScores(const struct Player*);

void displayNumberRound(const int);
void displayResultPlayer(const struct Player*, const int);
void displayMessageAboutVictory(const int);

void ncursesDisplayNumberRound(const int);
void ncursesDisplayResultPlayer(const struct Player*, const int);
void ncursesDisplayMessageAboutVictory(const int);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) exit(1);

    system("clear");
    srand(time(NULL));

    int           currentRound = 0;
    register int  countPlayers = atoi(argv[1]);
    struct Player players[countPlayers];

    for (int i = 0; i < countPlayers; ++i) players[i].allScores = 0;

    if (!strcmp(argv[2], "-r0"))
    {
        while (1)
        {
            currentRound++;
            displayNumberRound(currentRound);

            for (register int i = 0; i < countPlayers; i++)
            {
                players[i].firstDiceScores  = 1 + rand() % 6;
                players[i].secondDiceScores = 1 + rand() % 6;
                players[i].allScores       += changePlayerScores(&players[i]);

                displayResultPlayer(&players[i], i);

            }

            sleep(2);
            system("clear");
        }
    }
    else if (!strcmp(argv[2], "-r1"))
    {
        initscr();
        cbreak();
        noecho();

        while (1)
        {
            currentRound++;
            ncursesDisplayNumberRound(currentRound);

            for (register int i = 0; i < countPlayers; i++)
            {
                players[i].firstDiceScores  = 1 + rand() % 6;
                players[i].secondDiceScores = 1 + rand() % 6;
                players[i].allScores       += changePlayerScores(&players[i]);

                ncursesDisplayResultPlayer(&players[i], i);

                if (players[i].allScores >= 50)
                {
                    ncursesDisplayMessageAboutVictory(i);
                    endwin();
                    exit(0);
                }

                refresh();
            }

            sleep(2);
            system("clear");
        }

        endwin();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Incorrect arguments!");
        exit(1);
    }
}

//
// interceptKeystrokes
//

int interceptKeystroke() 
{
    struct termios oldt, newt;
    int            keyCode;

    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);

    newt          = oldt;
    newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);

    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);

    keyCode = getchar();

    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
    return keyCode;
}

//
// changePlayerScores
//

int changePlayerScores(const struct Player* _player)
{
    int receivedScores = 0;

    if (_player->firstDiceScores == _player->secondDiceScores)
    {
        switch (_player->firstDiceScores)
        {
            case 1:
                receivedScores = 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                receivedScores = 2;
                break;
            case 3:
                receivedScores = -_player->allScores;
                break;
            case 4:
                receivedScores = 4;
                break;
            case 5:
                receivedScores = 5;
                break;
            case 6:
                receivedScores = 25;
                break;
        }
    }

    return receivedScores;
}

//
// displayNumberRound
//

void displayNumberRound(const int _numberRound)
{
    printf(" ROUND %i\n", _numberRound);
}

//
// displayResultPlayer
//

void displayResultPlayer(const struct Player* _player, const int _playerNumber)
{   
    sleep(1);

    if (_playerNumber == 0)
    {
        printf(" Press any key for throw the dice...\n\n");

        interceptKeystroke();

        printf(" You get %i and %i. You scores = %i...\n", _player->firstDiceScores, _player->secondDiceScores, 
               _player->allScores);
    }
    else
    {
        printf(" Player %i get %i and %i. His scores = %i...\n", _playerNumber, _player->firstDiceScores, 
               _player->secondDiceScores, _player->allScores);
    }
}

//
// displayMessageAboutVictory
//

void displayMessageAboutVictory(const int _playerNumber)
{
    (_playerNumber == 0) ? printf(" You wins!\n") : printf(" Player '%i' wins!\n", _playerNumber);
}

//
// ncursesDisplayNumberRound
//

void ncursesDisplayNumberRound(const int _numberRound)
{
    attron(A_BOLD);
    printw(" ROUND %i\n", _numberRound);
    attroff(A_BOLD);
}

//
// ncursesDisplayResultPlayer
//

void ncursesDisplayResultPlayer(const struct Player* _player, const int _playerNumber)
{
    sleep(1);

    if (_playerNumber == 0)
    {
        printw(" ");

        attron(A_UNDERLINE);
        printw("Press any key for throw the dice...\n\n");
        attroff(A_UNDERLINE);

        getch();

        printw(" ");

        addch('-' | A_BOLD);

        printw(" You get %i and %i. You scores = %i...\n", _player->firstDiceScores, _player->secondDiceScores, 
               _player->allScores);
    }
    else
    {
        printw(" ");

        addch('-' | A_BOLD);

        printw(" Player %i get %i and %i. His scores = %i...\n", _playerNumber, _player->firstDiceScores, 
               _player->secondDiceScores, _player->allScores);
    }
}


//
// ncursesDisplayMessageAboutVictory
//

void ncursesDisplayMessageAboutVictory(int _playerNumber)
{
    (_playerNumber == 0) ? printw("You wins!\n") : printw("Player '%i' wins!\n", _playerNumber);
}
```

Все нормально компилируется и работает: `clang-3.6 -lncurses dice.c -o dice`.
При параметре `-r0` (т.е. без `ncurses`) работает без ошибок постоянно (по крайней мере до 74-го раунда), но, если использовать `ncurses`, то с 7-го раунда текст "комкается", а на 8-мом остается пару символов и программа не работает.

В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все дело в функции `system("clear")` - вместо нее нужно использовать `erase`.